# Pi Router That serves both Ethernet and Wifi

Tags: wifi

Before I have setup my Pi 2 as a Router that has 2 ethernet connections, the extra one is a USB 100Mbit Ethernet adatper, eth0 for incoming internet and eth1 for outgoing LAN.

But this time I want to this again but also with a Wifi access point using a USB wifi adapter I have.

How can I do this?

Edit:  So far the 2 answers do not understand that The Pi will have 3 basic network interfaces - eth0, eth1 and wlan0.  And not just eth0 and wlan0. So I want a Pi Router that serves both Ethernet LAN AND Wifi LAN.

Comment: My question is not a duplicate if people would actually understand what I wrote.